# 10 topics, 5 exam questions, what is the probability 2 topics show up?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have an upcoming exam, with 5 questions that may cover 10 topics. Suppose I want to accept a 90% probability of my studied exam questions showing up, how many topics should I study? What is the relevant combinatorial calculation here?

If I study 2 topics, what's the chance of these both showing up in my exam?

---

Assume that each question is on a different topic.

Comment: Do you mean 90% probability of your studied exam *topics* showing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question:
$$\frac{1\cdot 1\cdot\binom{8}{3}}{\binom{10}{5}}\approx 22.2\%.$$

It's a little bit counter-intuitive that if you study 3 topics and you want them all show up the chance decrease.

### Edit:

With the help from the comment I just figure it out. For your first question you have to study at least 3 questions so at least one of them will should up and fit your criterion, that is:

$$1-\frac{\binom{7}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}} \approx 91.7\%$$

---

### Bonus:

Prepare $6$, at least $3$ shows up:

Total $-$ (only shows up 1 $+$ only shows up 2) :

$$1-\frac{\Bigl(\binom{4}{4}\cdot\binom{6}{1}\Bigr)+\Bigl(\binom{4}{3}\cdot\binom{6}{2}\Bigr)}{\binom{10}{5}}\approx74\%.$$

I would recommend you to at least study about 6 topics so the probability you pass the exam, assume each scores $20$ and the total is $100$, is about $75\%$.

Comment: The more topics you study, the greater the chance that at least one of them will show up on the test but the smaller the chance that all of them will show up on the test.